# Httpclient with 2 headers requests

Tags: c#

I need to connect to editor's software PHP Api Post Json and I need to add in a header for authentication:

- "Token" + key
- "Content-Type", "application/json"

I have my content

```
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtu, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
   NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
}));
ByteArrayContent(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content));
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```

I then try to connect to the API

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", config.readStringKey("token"));
    var result = client.PostAsync(baseurl, content)
        .ResultContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

But I need to add the second line in headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue like

Screen capture https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXkTv.jpg

How do I do this?

Comment: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` is to set the `Authorization` header. You're not doing the same thing in Postman. In Postman you're setting the `Token` header.

Comment: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token", config.readStringKey("token"))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use default request headers if reciever allows it:

```
// depending on token encoding you can add 'Token' to default headers dictionary. in this case: a bearer token
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("content-type", "application/json"));
```